# embed video on website using django-embed-video

Tags: python, django

when run it gives an error: Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist at /
Exception Value: video.html
and also: return render(request,'video.html',{'obj':obj})

```
views.py:

from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Item

def video(request):
   obj = Item.objects.all()
   return render(request,'video.html',{'obj':obj})

video.html:

{% load embed_video_tags %}
<!doctype html>
<html lang="ru">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Демо Bootstrap</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Привет мир!</h1>
    {% block content %}
        {% for i in obj %}
        {% video i.video 'small' %}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endblock %}
  </body>
</html>
```

I searched how to fix the error on YouTube and did not find anything

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NA1id.png)

Comment: Can you show where the directory layout, where is this template stored. Because this error has nothing to do with the content of the file, Django can't find `video.html` in the templates directory. Please also show the settings.py part where this is `TEMPLATES = [xxxx]`

Comment: TEMPLATES = [
            'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')
                     ],   .......